# Rails open OpenSLL error on: Rails g jquery:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting a OpenSSL error, when I try when I run rails g jquery:install.

My rails console:

```
C:\Rails\konkurranceportalen>rails g jquery:install
      remove  public/javascripts/controls.js
      remove  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      remove  public/javascripts/effects.js
      remove  public/javascripts/prototype.js
    fetching  jQuery (1.5)
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery.js
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery.min.js
    fetching  jQuery UJS adapter (github HEAD)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:677:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 e
rrno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL
::SSL::SSLError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:677:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:769:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:671:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/fi
le_manipulation.rb:77:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-0.2.7/lib/generato
rs/jquery/install/install_generator.rb:34:in `download_ujs_driver'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22
:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:124:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:124:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:124:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:124:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:2
26:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:38
9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/genera
tors.rb:163:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/generate.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Rails\konkurranceportalen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/issues/17) is an issue discussing something similar. Assembler says the following:

> for quickfix, add following lines to
>   "environment.rb":
>
> `require 'openssl'`
>
> `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER =
>   OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`
>
> make sure that you remove those lines
>   after you install jquery-rails

Comment: Why should it be removed after I have installed jquery-rails? Can you explain what OpenSSL does?

Comment: the thinking is that after you have jquery installed you no longer need this.

Comment: It is just because I also get this error when I try to submit an email form